# Shrink logicial volume when it has snapshots

Tags: linux, lvm, cloud

Basically, we can shrink logical volume by **lvreduce** or **resize** command as below:

```
lvreduce/lvresize -L 2G [logicial volume path]
```

but, when the lv has snapshots(snapshot origin volumes) the shrink command would fail with error output below:

```
Snapshot origin volumes cannot be reduced in size yet.
```

Actually we can extend lv at this case, why the shrink commands are not supported? my environment is:

```
Linux SZX1000159695 3.13.0-106-generic #153-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 6 15:44:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is there any possibility that we can support shrink lv which has snapshots?

Answer (score 0):

Shrinking is a lot harder to do then expanding a volume - because when you add space you know it has not been used yet.

When you do a snapshot, it keeps a diff between the data in the origin and the data in the snapshot.

When shrinking a volume, you are getting rid of extents (ie space) - but what if, when the snapshot was created, there was data in that space ?   If there was data in the space, when you reduce it, there is no longer data there, so you can't make a diff of the data that is not there.

It is, I am sure, possible for LVM to get updated to handle this, but it will require quite a bit of coding, which could cause bugs and data loss, and which, it appears, has not been implemented.